# Safari 5, auto enable private mode (without AppleScript launcher)

Tags: macos, safari, privacy

Is this possible? Easy enough to achieve with AppleScript, but I don't want a separate launcher in the dock.

Answer (score 1):

The brief research and testing I've done seems to indicate that the plist setting `WebKitPrivateBrowsingEnabled` always defaults to false. The only way to enable private mode on launch is to use an AppleScript.

Some workarounds:

1. You could have an applescript that is always idling in the background to detect the launch of Safari. Put this applescript in your startup items. [Details here.](http://macosx.com/forums/1199085-post2.html)
2. You could add a keyboard shortcut to Private Browsing to make it easy to toggle on. [Details here.](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2007102722440633)
3. Maybe there's a way to do this with a new Safari Extension?